# Implicit declaration of getdate_r on OS X

Tags: c, macos, time.h

I am trying to use this C function with the following code:

```
struct tm *res = NULL;
result = getdate_r(temp->value, res);
```

However clang tells me this: `implicit declaration of function 'getdate_r' is invalid in C99`

I have the following includes:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <time.h>
```

Has anyone managed to use `getdate_r` on OS X?

Comment: Do you actually have GCC? I think in OS X, gcc is an alias for clang.  Try `gcc --version`.

Comment: My bad, it's clang. Am I SOL?

Comment: Yes; the C library on OS X does not appear to have `getdate_r()` as a function.  Note that POSIX specifies [`getdate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdate.html) but does not specify the re-entrant version `getdate_r()`.  Note that you are misusing [`getdate_r()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdate.3.html); you are expected to pass a non-null pointer to the function: `struct tm res; if (getdate_r(time_value, &res) != 0) { …error… }`.

Comment: `getdate_r` is a GNU extension.  Just doing `#define _GNU_SOURCE` doesn't magically give you GNU extensions.  You might not actually have it.  It's not mentioned in the [`man getdate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getdate.3.html) pages for OS X.  But it shows up in Linux man pages: [`man getdate`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getdate).

Comment: Oh well, the reentrant version of `getdate()` doesn't seem that much better than the original. Thanks!